# How to create a filter as a button on the Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

Someone created some filters for columns of data on a Google Sheet.  But they created  buttons for these filters on the sheet.  Can someone tell me how this was done?  I've attached a screenshot of what I'm trying to ask/convey.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Look into slicers.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556?hl=en)

Select your range, then go to `Data > Add a Slicer`.

Answer (score -1):

These are slicers.

They have used slicer to create these.

Go to "Data" tab from menu .. "add Slicer".